# Check the uniqueness using multiple columns including a substring of a field in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a database table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemX(
    code varchar(20),
    size varchar(12),
    type varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(code),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY F1(code) REFERENCES Item(code)   
);
```

code is similar to "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0001"

I need to check whether `(first 15 characters of code,size,type)` is unique before adding a row into the table. 
I tried `UNIQUE (SUBSTRING(code,1,15),size,type)` but it didn't work.
How could I achieve this??

Comment: First 15 characters of all 3 columns or just `code`?

Comment: sorry. yes only in code field.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `ItemX` ADD UNIQUE `ui`(`code`, `size`, `type`);
```

I'm not sure if MySQL will allow you pass in a function of a column when creating a unique constraint.  If you really want to use only the first 15 characters of the `code` column, you might want to create a new column for this purpose.